# Anonymous arrow functions in objects

Tags: javascript, object, arrow-functions

How is it that this syntax works:

```js
let foo = 0; // or 1
let bar = {
   foo: foo || function (x) { return 'foo ' + x; }
};

// If foo is 0
bar.foo('bar'); // Returns 'foo bar'
// If foo is 1
bar.foo; // Returns 1
```

and this one doesn't:

```js
let foo = 0; // or 1
let bar = {
   foo: foo || (x) => { return 'foo ' + x; }
};
```

If I try to run the bottom example, I get the `Malformed arrow function parameter list` error in the console. How is it `Malformed`, and what would the correct syntax be to get the same functionality as the top example?

Comment: let bar = { foo: foo || ((x) => 'foo ' + x) }

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the arrow function doesn't know how to group the parameters. You should wrap the function in parenthesis as such:

```js
let foo = 1
let bar = {
   foo: foo || (x => { return 'foo ' + x; })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt use js for a while but I think

```
let bar = {
   foo: foo || (x => { 'foo' + x })
};
```

should do the job

greetings